# Finding a sequence of functions which is dense in $L^p([0,1])$ for $p\in[1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I already know that the set of simple functions, polynomials, and continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^p([0,1])$, for $p\in[1,\infty)$.

But my real analysis problem asks to find a **sequence** of functions which is dense in $L^p$. The problem on me is that these given examples are not countable.

One of my idea is to give an enumeration on the set of all polynomials with rational coefficient. Is this a correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $p$ is a polynomial, say $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_kx^{k}$ then there exist rational numbers $b_k, 1 \leq k \leq n$,  such that $\int |f-g|^{p} <\epsilon$ where $g=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} b_kx^{k}$ (Use triangle inequality). Polynomials with rational coefficients form a countable family.